# Android push message without gcm possible?

Tags: android, push-notification

Is there any possibility to implement push-messages to android without google cloud messaging?

I already took a view on openmobster but it does not satisfy my needs.

I need to:

- create push-messages to an android device
- self-hosted

A complete sync-framework (with REST) for android would even be better :)

Thank you

Comment: Can you elaborate why OpenMobster does not satisfy your needs. From your question it seems like it would work out fine.

It consists of both just Push notifications and a Sync Framework integrated with Push notifications without using the GCM service.

I would like to know what part did you not like about the project so that I can make it better. Your feedback is much appreciated...

Comment: Actually i like openmobster very much. Due to some requirements i need to do RPC calls and other things. I cant use a fully provided backend. For other approaches openmobster will surely work very fine :)

Comment: @openmobster (Sohil Shah) it would be great if openmobster provides GCM as thirparty Push notification as option, including it's own!

Comment: It looks like [OpenMobster is not developed/maintained anymore](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/openmobster-users/AX8-rbA4cfg)...

Comment: Consider a paid product Pushy (https://pushy.me/), an independent, reliable push notification gateway that does not depend on GCM. You can also self-host this product on-premises. Full disclosure - I am the Founder & CEO at Pushy.

Comment: check this questions for more comprehensive [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20329403/android-push-notification-without-using-gcm)

Answer (score 0):

Rabbitmq works perfectly fine, but I dont know about effectiveness. Roaring Rabbit of CloudAMQP.com is supporting only 100 concurrent connections and 229$ per month. What if you have more than 100 mobiles that are currently connected to rabbit. I made the push with cloudamqp.com' little lemure. May be you need to have a rabbitmq server in ec2.

Answer (score -3):

You can check with Parse library

https://www.parse.com/docs/android_guide

You can also see userban airship.

https://docs.urbanairship.com/display/DOCS/Home

Comment: I think this was down voted because Parse uses GCM under the covers.