# Android Push Notification without using GCM

Tags: android, push-notification

I need brief steps to implement GCM without using android's standard way. Instead, I need to set up my own central server for device registration and upload file from server to registered device without using GCM.

I also need some suggestions to block certain applications via admin console(For example: Need to choose and send a notification to a particular device to block user to launch Gmail/Google Play application installed on device). It's more like the concept of Mobile application Management. Let me have suggestions on these.

Comment: Do you have any reason for not using gcm? You can do all of these with it

Comment: @inankupeli.. For security concern we don't want to expose device details to outside world.

Comment: @inankupeli Another reason is that some people (including me) have disabled Google Play Services and don't use Google Account on their Android phones (I don't like how Google treats our privacy, but I still use Android without a problems and without Google Account).

Comment: Consider a paid product Pushy (https://pushy.me/), an independent, reliable push notification gateway that does not depend on GCM. You can also self-host this product on-premises for your data privacy concerns. Full disclosure - I am the Founder & CEO at Pushy.

Comment: @SenthilMg have you been successful in creating a Push Notification server without using GCM or FCM?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

A few things to get your started:

**MQTT / Paho**
The Paho project provides open-source client implementations of MQTT and MQTT-SN messaging protocols aimed at new, existing, and emerging applications for Machine‑to‑Machine (M2M) and Internet of Things (IoT).
http://www.eclipse.org/paho/
https://developer.motorolasolutions.com/docs/DOC-2315

**AndroidPN**
This is an open source project to provide push notification support for Android. A xmpp based notification server and a client tool kit. 
https://sourceforge.net/projects/androidpn/

**Tutorail**
Quick example on how to implement push notifications for your Android app using MQTT protocol. I will NOT discuss here why an application might need push notifications or the advantages of Push over Pull. I assume that you know exactly what I mean by push notifications are and why you might need them. However, before jumping in straight to the good stuff, let’s go over how it all started.
http://tokudu.com/post/50024574938/how-to-implement-push-notifications-for-android

**The Deacon Project (Deprecated)**
The Deacon Project aims to produce an open-source push notifications library for the Android platform. “Deacon” is a Java class library used by Android developers to receive Push notifications from a Meteor comet web server. “Deacon-Demo” (http://github.com/davidrea/Deacon-Demo/) is an Android app that is used for testing and demonstration of Deacon, and is also developed by members of the Deacon project.
https://github.com/davidrea/Deacon

**Similar Question:**
[Android push message without gcm possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14629490/android-push-message-without-gcm-possible)

In addition, if you'd like to have your own server but would still let GCM take care of delivery (it really is one of the cheapest, if not free, and reliable ways to send notifications) there are lot's of alternatives. Like [PushJet](http://docs.pushjet.io) [PushKin](http://pushkin.io) and [much more](https://github.com/search?o=desc&q=android%20push%20notification&s=stars&type=Repositories&utf8=%E2%9C%93).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm bit confused to configure the   central server ..Provide me some basic stuff to configure local server.

Comment: I probably can't explain more than is already discribed here: https://github.com/davidrea/Deacon/wiki/Server-setup