# Push notificacions in Android without Google Play Services

Tags: android, parse-platform

We are working in a project with a TomTom tablet and we realised that the Android version of TomTom comes without Google Play Services.

We thought on Parse or some similar push service, but we are not sure if they also need Google Play Services for working.

Is there any better solution before doing Pulling?

Comment: Parse also uses Google Play Services.

Comment: Thanks Madhur, any alternative solution?

Comment: Have a look here.
(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20329403/android-push-notification-without-using-gcm)

Comment: There are alternative push gateways such as Pushy (https://pushy.me/) that do not depend on Google Play Services, establishing their own connection instead to receive push notifications. Full disclosure - I am the Founder & CEO at Pushy.

Answer (score 0):

May be you could see [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) . It is open source and free

Answer (score 0):

parse required google play services but you can do it through gcm jar file .... google cloud messaging is different and gcm.jar is different .
you can follow this [example](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/)