# How can I send notifications if my app is closed?

Tags: android, android-studio, notifications, android-alarms

How can I send my user notifications during the day if my app is closed? It should also work if he hasn't opened the app after a reboot of his phone. How can I implement something like that in my app and what things should I learn for that?
Thanks!

Comment: Please explain, in detail, what "send my user notifications" means. What is the trigger for these notifications?

Comment: Notifications where users get an reminder for something in the app. Like an alarm or something like that. Like in Tinder when they tell you per notification that you are able to swipe right again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to schedule a task using Alarm Manager](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16889775/how-to-schedule-a-task-using-alarm-manager)

Answer (score 0):

Push Notifications come through GCM (google cloud messaging) on Android. In order to see a tutorial on this you can go to https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-push-notification-using-gcm-tutorial/

As per "it should also work if he hasn't opened the app after a reboot of his phone" part, once you register your app with the client, you can employ logic of what happens (or doesn't happen) when you logout of the app. For example, you can unregister from the service so you don't get any notifications.

In your case, if you'd like to keep receiving notifications then you can do so by making sure you keep your token alive, preferably in System Preferences, and handle the case of what happens if the token needs to be updated. (see onTokenRefresh() callback)

First do the happy path and see you can register and receive, and then go and do any additional logic for your notifications.

Comment: but is there a way to do this offline because with Google cloud messaging the app needs internet access right?

Comment: yes, but GCM will put the notification in a queue and deliver it once the device is able to receive the push again. If you would like to implement push notifications without GCM, look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20329403/android-push-notification-without-using-gcm

Comment: ok but is there an offline solution where you don't need any internet access?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `AlarmManager` for this. It will wake your Application with an scheduled Intent where you can perform your code, e.g. show the notification.

seems to be a duplicate to [How to schedule a task using Alarm Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16889775/how-to-schedule-a-task-using-alarm-manager)