# How to send a notification to users when mysql database value is updated/changed without using GCM and fire-base?

Tags: php, android, mysql, database, notifications

I am creating an android application which uses the PHP/MySQL database employee details.
my database contains the details like schedule date and hours etc,

I have two questions

1. I want to check the database at regular interval of time like if there is any change in schedule date and hours notify the user.
2. how to send the notification to the users when the admin set the scheduled date and hours for an employee or modify the hours in database.

send notification like
"your schedule has been created"
or
"your schedule hour has been changed"

But I should not use Firebase and `gcm` method. 
Is there is any way to send the notification to the user without using Firebase and `gcm`?

this is my PHP file which will receive the data from the database and send to android application.

```
    <?php
require "init.php";
$name = $_POST["name"];
$password = $_POST["password"];   
  //$name = "rajesh";
  //$password = "1995";
        $Sql = "SELECT * FROM `user_info` 
        WHERE `name`='".$name."' AND 
        `password`='".$password."';";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $Sql);
    $retrive = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $user_id =  $row['id']; 
        $sql = "SELECT id, ScheduleDate, StartTime,Endtime, Hours,Employeeid 
        FROM empdet WHERE Employeeid ='".$user_id."' ";
        $result = $con->query($sql);     
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
        {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
            {
            $id=$row["id"]. 
            $date=$row["ScheduleDate"]; 
            $start=$row["StartTime"]; 
            $end=$row["Endtime"];
            $hour=$row["Hours"];
            $Employeeid=$row["Employeeid"];
            list($year,$month,$day) = split("-",$date);
            $data[] = array("year"=>$year,
                            "month"=>$month,
                            "day"=>$day,
                            "StartTime"=>$start,
                            "Endtime"=>$end,
                            "Hours"=>$hour );   
            }
                $response = $data;
        }
        else
            {
            $data=1;
            $response = $data;
            }   
    }

if($response==null )
{
    echo "USERNAME/PASSWORD IS INCORRECT";
}
else
{
     if($response==1)
     {
         echo "NO SCHEDULE FOUND";
     } 
     else
     {
     echo json_encode(array("user_data"=> $response));
     }
}

?>
```

[image: This is my database]
here I want to check the database for change or modify at the regular interval, and send the notification to the android application of the particular user without using gcm and firebase.

Comment: For 1, you need to use Cron jobs to run tasks at intervals — https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/scheduling-tasks-with-cron-jobs--net-8800  For sending push without GCM, check the answers at https://stackoverflow.com/q/20329403/816416 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/14629490/816416.

Comment: i need example code, so that i create them with my project details.
 code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ "page no found"

Comment: It's a full url - https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/scheduling-tasks-with-cron-jobs--net-8800 - click on it rather than copy-pasting it.

Comment: i saw the website , but not able to understand it, is there is any example code ?

Comment: @selvasurya Did you find any solution to this?