# Notifying Android device via Internet without gcm

Tags: android, push-notification

The user download my `.apk` and install it. Then, from time to time my php server should inform his phone about "new message", **even if the user is not currently running my application** (but it can run as service).

How to achieve it without using the gcm? The message is a simple "ping" ("new message") that will cause the Android application to get the message.

**I cannot be limited to the users that have Google Play Services enabled** and gcm require it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android push message without gcm possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14629490/android-push-message-without-gcm-possible)

Comment: If you don't want to use push notifications then here is the thing you can run your android service indefinitely which will fetch current data or whatever your application requires to show in every few mins.

Comment: Since you are looking for a push notification solution that does not require Google Play Services, check out Pushy (https://pushy.me/), an independent notification service that works without Google Play Services. Full disclosure - I founded Pushy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try use 3rd push notification library. Such as parse https://parse.com/tutorials/android-push-notifications

Comment: Isn't parse an paid solution?

Comment: Fix: Parse seems to use its own gcm architect. Pardon me.