# Android - How to notify the user one row is updated in data base

Tags: java, android, mysql

We developed a Hotel Menu Order project in android. Now We have created the project successfully. We are using `java`, `Jax-rs` for web service, `Mysql` for database and `Rest` for communication.

Now we want to add some more features in our app. When the customer conforms their order that order should show to kitchen and admin. When we google for some example we found one way. That is `Google Cloud Messaging`. But this is online sevice. We can not use this service.

Because we are using in offline services. We use one centralized server in the hotel and all the devices will connect with WiFi. There is no internet connection.

In this case how to notify the user a row is updated in Database. Please let us know how to achieve this.

Comment: via sms, you can send sms to the devices and send the content in it. On device end you can check the number and the sms text and perform action on client side.

Comment: I think you can search for push notification in android.

Comment: @RoshanBharti.. GCM is online service. But we need offline service..

Comment: @NamanGala.. Is it possible to send Push notification from local server with out internet connections??

Comment: @NewDeveloper, I don't have any idea on how to use it without internet connection.

Comment: @NewDeveloper, you can have a look at this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14629490/android-push-message-without-gcm-possible).

Answer (score 0):

Via SMS, what you can do is that you can send the sms to the devices using thrid party services like [twilio](https://www.twilio.com/sms), on client side i.e. device end you can get the sms broadcast validate the number and the sms content, read the content and update the application DB and the UI accordingly.

Or if one device has internet then what you can do is send GCM notification to that device, and from that device you can update the other devices through wifi direct. But wifi direct has some limitation, I think using SMS is a better option.

Comment: Raza.. Thanks for the quick response. But we need any open source solutions.

Comment: you can find many sample online, please search it your self. I gave you an idea, put some effort to find how to implement it. There are many example solution out there, google it. Google is your best friend my friend remember it.

Comment: see this, https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/android-client and http://androidexample.com/Incomming_SMS_Broadcast_Receiver_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=62&aaid=87 you will have some idea, you can search more if there is something that is not clear

Comment: :-) .. Thanks friend.. I will google it and let you know if I found the solution..

Comment: Sorry.. We can not send SMS. Because we are using tablets. In some tablets there is no SIM option :-( ...

Comment: Then my friend the logic that you have to implement should be like this, notify the devices via sms (these will be the devices that have the sim) now once a device is updated now you have to communicate between devices you can use wifi direct or bluetooth,if not more then 10 meters then you can use bluetooth for communication. If there is an other appropriate idea please do share.

Comment: what solution did you implemented in the end?

Answer (score 0):

u can use Google Cloud Messenger services, by which google provide free message service to your client. http://hmkcode.com/android-google-cloud-messaging-tutorial/ this example will help u to understand  better.

Comment: Is it possible to send and receive notification in offline.?? Because I mention in my question we need offline notification..

Comment: Here you are using google cloud services, these services are required internet connection for client side.