# How can I add notifications to my news App ANDROID?

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin, rss

I am working on a android news app which gets news from google news rss feed. I am currently getting news and showing it to the user in my app. But I want to show notification to the user when new news appears on google rss. I have no idea how to do it as I am new to android and could not find anything relevant on google. Thank you.

Here is my code I have done so far

```
internal static List<FeedItem> GetFeedItems(string url)
        {

            List<FeedItem> feedItemsList = new List<FeedItem>();
            try
            {
                HttpClient wc = new HttpClient();

                var html = wc.GetStringAsync(new Uri(url)).Result;


                XElement xmlitems = XElement.Parse(html);
                // We need to create a list of the elements
                List<XElement> elements = xmlitems.Descendants("item").ToList();

                // Now we're putting the informations that we got in our ListBox in the XAML code
                // we have to use a foreach statment to be able to read all the elements 
                // Description  , Link , Title are the attributes in the RSSItem class that I've already added
                List<FeedItem> aux = new List<FeedItem>();
                foreach (XElement rssItem in elements)
                {
                    FeedItem rss = new FeedItem();

                    rss.Description = rssItem.Element("description").Value;
                    rss.Link = rssItem.Element("link").Value;
                    rss.Title = rssItem.Element("title").Value;
                    feedItemsList.Add(rss);

                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
            return feedItemsList;
        }
```

Comment: I think you should create a service which triggers when internet is turned on, and in that service retrieve the news and show notification. If you want a continuously check use an AlarmManger inside the service and check repeatedly for news updates

Comment: @Boss how can I check if a news is already shown by my app ?

Comment: use a db. save a boolean variable when news is shown. (This question is primarily opinion based. You shouldn't ask such questions here in SO)

Answer (score 1):

Use parse's push notification,it's very easy to use and has great documents.
https://parse.com

Answer (score 0):

go for push notification service. its the only way to get the notification .

follow this tutorial... http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

Comment: I am not supposed to use GCM. I am new and can not use it. :)

Comment: u can ..its easy only follow the all steps which mentioned in above tutorial. this is the best working tutorial ever.

Comment: @ShivanshuVerma that method is deprecated, I think

Comment: no, i  recently used this in my application,and its working fine.

Comment: Am I supposed to buy subscription or what ?

Comment: @ShivanshuVerma deprecated doesn't means that it won't work, it means it is not recommended and a new method is introduced.

Comment: @Boss can u give me the detailed link? as i dn't have any idea about new method. but i guess this method is also not deprecated.

Comment: @Boss can I do it without using cloud. creating a local service or something ?

Comment: @soumyasambitKunda no need to buy any suvscription for using GCM in android. its free of cost

Comment: @soumyasambitKunda  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14629490/android-push-message-without-gcm-possible   visit here

Comment: @ShivanshuVerma In that example for GCM registration they are using `GCMBaseIntentService `. its deprecated.  for new method refer these. 1. https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/android/gcm. 2. https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start

Answer (score 0):

Notification manager is what you want here.

see this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html ?

A simple google search also shows tutorials for the same

Comment: Its all about the notification but How can I customize as per my requirement. Should I check the rss url time to time then check if any new and show a notification or what ?